# Permission to edit own unpublished content (only)?

Tags: 7, users

I have a content type Poll with an unpublished option. When a user creates a poll the poll remains unpublished for 1 hour and after that it becomes published (done with rules).

What i want to achieve is: Give the Poll author the permission to edit his poll node only while it is unpublished. **When it gets published this permission will expire.**

How can i work this out?

Comment: i guess this is a tough one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hook_node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) to the rescue!  You need to create a new module to do this.  In the new module's .module file you'll need to put this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  // Deny updating the content if it's a published poll
  if ($node->type == 'poll' && $node->status && $op == 'update') {
    drupal_set_message('This poll has been published, you may not make changes to it.','error');
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You saved me from a lot of research.