# Allow users to edit own unpublished content

Tags: nodes, users

I would like to provide users with *role-A* and *role-B* the ability to edit their own published and unpublished content. I've installed the [Content Access Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) and seems impossible to make this without coding. Does anyone know how to solve with code?

Comment: you can use hook_node_access as described in this thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63237/permission-to-edit-own-unpublished-content-only

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your exact requirement. If you want to list all contents created by current user with an edit link, my suggestion to make try with **[views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)**.

1. Give **Edit Own Content** permission to your **needed roles** for all content types in **Home » Administration » People » Permissions**.
2. Create a view with **content of all**.
3. Add title in fields (or the fields you want).
4. If you want to give an **edit link** , add **Content:Edit Link**.
5. In views contextual filter add **Content:Author uid = User ID from logged in user** (Refer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/drupal-7-view-filtering-on-node-uid-equal-to-current-user/179694)).
6. Change format to **Table** (Only title and edit link is there this gives a nice formatting).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: With this i can provide my actually view with and edit button but it doesn't change the permission. When i click on edit i see **You are not authorized...**

Comment: Give **Edit Own Content** permission to **needed roles** for all content types in **Home » Administration » People » Permissions**.

Comment: Yew i've all permissions set under **node**

Comment: The only way i've found to see the **Edit** tab is to check the _Bypass the control access to content_, first check under **Node** in permissions page... but it's not a really good solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your own module:

```
function MODULE_permission() {
    return array(
        'edit own unpublished content' => array(
            'title' => t('Edit own unpublished content'),
            'description' => t('Allow user to edit own unpublished content.'),
        ),
    );
}

function MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
    if (user_access("edit own unpublished content") && $op == "update" && $node->status == 0 && $node->uid == $account->uid) {
        return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
}
```

It will add a permission that is applicable to all nodes. If you want to set it for a specific bundle only you will have to expand on it a bit.

Comment: It does not work. Even after run permissions rebuilt

Comment: Try on a clean install to assure yourself that it works, then look at module calling order as it may have an effect.